# Show that $K$ is compact in $C \left[a, b \right]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma >0$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b$. Put 
$$K = \left\{ f\in C[a, b]: \left|f(a) \right| \le \gamma,\; \left|f(x) - f(y) \right|\le \beta \left| x-y \right|^\alpha, \;\forall x, y \in [a,b] \right\}.$$
Show that $K$ is compact in $C[a,b]$.

Since $C[a, b]$ is complete metric space, so if $K$ is closed and totally bounded then $K$ is compact. I want to show that $K$ is totally bounded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Arselà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem)?

Comment: I don't think that it is similar to Arsela- Ascoli theorem. We can prove it if we use A-A theorem?

Comment: So you *do* know it. The equicontinuity of $K$ is an easy consequence of the definition. Prove it, and you're done. Well, almost. Perhaps you mistyped the definition of $K$? Should the first inequality be $|f(a)|\le\gamma$? Otherwise, the statement is not correct as written.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen..... And then show that K is closed.

Comment: yes, we must have $\left| f(a) \right| \le \gamma$. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Using Arselà- Ascoli theorem. I want to show that:

(i) $\forall x_0 \in [a, b], \left\{ f(x_0) / f \in K \right\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}.$

(ii) $\forall x_0 \in [a, b], \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists$ neighbor $U$ of $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left| f(x) - f(x_0) \right| < \epsilon$, $\forall x \in U, f \in K$.
Then $K$ is totally bounded.

Proof:

(i) $\forall x_0 \in [a, b]$, we have

$$\left| f(x_0) \right| \le \left| f(x_0) -f(a) \right|+ \left| f(a) \right|  \le \beta \left|x_0 -a \right|^\alpha + \gamma, \forall f \in K.$$

So $\left\{ f(x_0) / f \in K \right\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}.$

(ii)  $\forall x_0 \in [a, b], \forall \epsilon > 0$, choose $ U = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} / \left| x - x_0 \right| <( \epsilon/ \beta )^{1/\alpha} \right\}$. Then $\forall x \in U, f \in K$, we have

$$\left| f(x) - f(x_0 \right| \le \beta|x- x_0|^\alpha < \epsilon. $$

So (ii) is satisfied.